# How to render unicode escape sequences using javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, internationalization

Below code,

```
document.writeln("Caracteres escapados {\u55e8\uff0c\u4f60\u597d\u5417}: "
                                                    + "\u55e8\uff0c\u4f60\u597d\u5417");
```

expected output is `\u55e8\uff0c\u4f60\u597d\u5417: 嗨，你好吗`

Current output is: `Caracteres escapados {嗨，你好吗}: 嗨，你好吗`

What modification is required in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes and remove the braces.

```
document.writeln("Caracteres escapados \\u55e8\\uff0c\\u4f60\\u597d\\u5417 "
                                                    + "\u55e8\uff0c\u4f60\u597d\u5417");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the backslashes of the codes you want to show without translating:

```js
document.writeln("Carácteres escapados \\u55e8\\uff0c\\u4f60\\u597d\\u5417: \u55e8\uff0c\u4f60\u597d\u5417");
```